# Write parts of file to file without loading into memory

Tags: php, file

I am using this code:

```
// write parts of file to file
file_put_contents($file,file_get_contents($ar, NULL, NULL, $s, $e));
```

to write parts of one file into a new file.

How could I do this using `stream_copy_to_stream`, or any other method that does this without loading file into memory?

Comment: If your file is big, instead of reading the complete content with `file_get_contents`, you could open manually the file with `fopen`, and then copy by piece with `fread` and `fwrite`. If your file is on local directory, you can also use basic command `copy` to make a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make some search on php.net, you can easily find an example that will make what you need. YOu can also use my advice on comments of your question.

```
<?php

$src = fopen('http://www.example.com', 'r');
$dest1 = fopen('first1k.txt', 'w');
$dest2 = fopen('remainder.txt', 'w');

echo stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest1, 1024) . " bytes copied to first1k.txt\n";
echo stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest2) . " bytes copied to remainder.txt\n";

?>
```

But, depending on your PHP version, it seems to be quite a memory hog.
The way with `fopen`, `fread` and `fwrite` can then be

```
<?php

    function customCopy($in, $out)
    {
        $size = 0;

        while (!feof($in))
            $size += fwrite($out, fread($in,8192));

        return $size;
    }

?>
```

Assuming `$in` and `$out` are file handler resources.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
  $fp = fopen($ar, "r");
  $out = fopen($file, "wb");
  fseek($fp, $se);
  while ($data = fread($fp, 2000)){
      fwrite($out, $data);
  }
  fclose($out);
  fclose($fp);
```